# ProgressDialog is stuck when onPause in asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a ProgressDialog in my Asynctask that count from 60 sec to 0, and then disapears ( onPostExecute )

The problem is that in 60 sec, it is common that screen turns down --> onPause

When I turn on my screen, my Dialog is stuck to X sec, and will not disapear.

I have to kill app. Is there a way to manage it???

Answer (score 0):

You can override onPause in your activity and handle your progress dialog there.  onPause is the event that occurs when your application loses focus. In this example below, I'm using onPause to check the reason we lost focus - if it's because the screen timed out, I take one action, if it's for other reasons (switch apps?) I take another.

```
@TargetApi(20)
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        PowerManager pm =(PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        Boolean screenOn = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 20 ? pm.isScreenOn() : pm.isInteractive();
        if(!isChangingConfigurations() && screenOn){
            //TODO take action for non screen sleep event
        } else {
            //TODO take action for screen sleep event
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
```